# How do I calculate Pixel based on Percentage for CSS conversion?

Tags: html, css, image, pixel, percentage

Hy we have a code in which we round an image by giving `border-radius:50%` but my teacher asked me
Using pixel instead of percentage .
my question is that how to round an images by using pixel unit instead of percentage unit..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Practice</title>
    <style>
    .logo img{
        width:60px;
        height:60px;
        border-radius:50%;    
        margin-left:5%;
    }
    </style>   
</head>

<body>

 <div class="logo">
    <img src="Images/icon.png" />
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the element is `60px x 60px`, `border-radius: 50%` is equivalent to `border-radius: 30px/30px` (50% of both sides).

Something like this:

```css
.logo {
   background-color: red;
   width: 60px;
   height: 60px;
   border-radius: 30px/30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
</div>
```

Comment: also border-radius:30px;

Comment: It will only be when width and height are the same, but if they are different then we need to have like this. So it's kind of generalized.